# Can Sylpheed Mail Be Configured To Allow For On-The-Fly Custom 'From' Email Addresses?

Tags: email

can i configure Sylpheed Mail (version 3.8) so that i can easily input a custom 'From' email address whenever i compose an email?

in particular, even though i may have configured

```
thisemail@thatdomain.tld
```

as my email address for a mail account in Sylpheed, can i have the option of changing the 'From' email address on-the-fly to

```
somethingelse@thatdomain.tld
```

or

```
anything@thatdomain.tld
```

etc. when i wish to compose a new email message?

i know i can change the email address of an account by going to

```
Configuration > Edit accounts...
```

and replace, for example, thisemail@thatdomain.tld with somethingelse@thatdomain.tld before composing an email, but is there a more straightforward way to configure Sylpheed so that i may have the custom 'From' email address option available to me after i select 'Compose' (an email) ?

thanks.

thed

.

.

Footnote: Sept. 6, 2023

prompted by Toto's comment below, i requested assistance to this question from Sylpheed (developers/contributors) by e-mailing:

```
Hiroyuki Yamamoto (hiro-y [at] kcn.ne.jp) on august 27, 2023

sylpheed [at] sraoss.jp and sylpheed-jp [at] sraoss.jp on august 31, 2023

Francois (barriere.francois [at] libertysurf.fr) on september 5, 2023

Petr (pknbe [at] volny.cz) on september 5, 2023 and

Paul Kater (paul [at] nlpagan.net) on september 5, 2023
```

all of these contact names/addresses were obtained either from within the Sylpheed program ('About' dialog box, version 3.8) or from various Sylpheed-info web sites ( e.g. https://sylpheeddoc.sourceforge.net/ https://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/ )

to date (Sept. 6, 2023) i have received no response, and no bounces of my e-mails sent to the above recipients

when/if i receive a response, i shall modify this post accordingly

.

.

Footnote: Sept. 8, 2023

Paul Kater (from the above Sylpheed list) was good enough to respond to me, however, they informed me that it has been 10 to 12 years since they worked on the Sylpheed manual, and have since "moved away from Sylpheed." their taking the time to respond is appreciated.

i'm not confident that i'll get any additional info. from past Sylpheed contributors.

Comment: Have you asked Sylpheed developpers?

Comment: Toto, yes i sent a Sylpheed developer an email requesting assistance - if they respond (and with a solution to the question i have posed here), i shall post the response here